# Javascript code-- What's wrong with function ToppingsWanted()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having some trouble with part of a JavaScript assignment. It involves using a couple of arrays: one with elements, one without as seen below. I've included all the code that is necessary for the arrays to work so you're not left in the dark about any details and I will explain as I go.

Below are two arrays. Array 'toppings' is filled with elements that also appear in a list box later on. The array below it, 'selectedToppings' is an empty array that will hold elements the user selects from the list box.

```
var toppings = [ "Sausage" , "Pepperoni" , "Extra Cheese" , "Onions" ,
"Black Olives" , "Anchovies" , "Pineapple" , "Canadian Bacon" , "Ground Beef" ];

var selectedToppings = [];
```

The function below is the output of the program. When I first wrote it, it didn't display anything because none of the function calls were right. What I've been doing recently is putting a semi-colon after each function call and making sure the appropriate function is working correctly before moving on to the next one. Right now I'm stuck on function ToppingsWanted(). You'll notice a semi-colon after "Amount Due: "--this is the semi-colon I referred to before. I'm pretty sure the function call is correct because functions quantity() and Size(), which come before it work perfectly.

```
function thankYou()
{
document.pizzaForm.OrderText.value="Thank you for your order from BHC Pizza!\nYou have
ordered " + quantity() + " " + Size() + " pizza(s) with\n" + ToppingsWanted() +
"AmountDue "; 
}
```

The function ToppingsWanted() you see below is what's giving me grief. I've tried numerous ways to get it to work, but nothing happens. I've visited this site, checked w3c schools, but couldn't find any answers to how to make this work. At this point I don't know enough about JavaScript arrays to know what's wrong here. What needs to happen is this: when a user selects a topping from the list box I mentioned earlier (code shown below the function), the appropriate element is taken from the toppings array and put into the selectedToppings array, and then the function call would display each element from the selectedToppings array on its own line. There aren't any syntax errors according to Dreamweaver, but I can't tell if there are any logic errors. Help?

```
function ToppingsWanted()
{
for (var i=0; i<10; i++);
{
    if (document.pizzaForm.lstIngredients.toppings[i].selected==true)
        selectedToppings.push[i];
}
var TopsSelect=selectedToppings.join("\n");
return TopsSelect;
}

<select name="lstIngredients" size="9" multiple="multiple">
        <option id="toppings[0]" value="1.00">Sausage</option>
        <option id="toppings[1]" value="1.00">Pepperoni</option>
        <option id="toppings[2]" value="1.00">Extra Cheese</option>
        <option id="toppings[3]" value="1.00">Onions</option>
        <option id="toppings[4]" value="1.00">Black Olives</option>
        <option id="toppings[5]" value="1.00">Anchovies</option>
        <option id="toppings[6]" value="1.00">Pineapple</option>
        <option id="toppings[7]" value="1.00">Canadian Bacon</option>
        <option id="toppings[8]" value="1.00">Ground Beef</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You should loop through `document.pizzaForm.lstIngredients.options` instead

Comment: That, plus you're not going to get what you think you are--right now you're just pushing the index, so you'll get a bunch of numbers with carriage returns as your string. I'd also stick to normal JS naming conventions.

Comment: You should give each option a different value, and collect the values in your result.

Comment: One thing I apologize for not clarifying is that the user is to able to select more than one item for a pizza, which is the reason for the loop and the second array.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve your problem. Just paste it in the body of your document

1. First you need to bind your ToppingsWanted() function to the onChange event of your list. So that when the state of the list changes your function gets fired.
2. Rather than loop through the list elements you can just get the selected one using the selectedIndex property.
3. I have changed the values to indices. now the function will get the value from your list which will be and index  0-8 and push the corresponding value to that index from your toppings array into your selected toppings array.

   ```
   <form name="pizzaForm">
       <select name="lstIngredients" size="9" multiple="multiple" onChange="ToppingsWanted()">
           <option id="toppings[0]" value="0">Sausage</option>
           <option id="toppings[1]" value="1">Pepperoni</option>
           <option id="toppings[2]" value="2">Extra Cheese</option>
           <option id="toppings[3]" value="3">Onions</option>
           <option id="toppings[4]" value="4">Black Olives</option>
           <option id="toppings[5]" value="5">Anchovies</option>
           <option id="toppings[6]" value="6">Pineapple</option>
           <option id="toppings[7]" value="7">Canadian Bacon</option>
           <option id="toppings[8]" value="8">Ground Beef</option>
       </select>   
   </form>

   <script type="text/javascript">

      var selectedToppings = [];

       var toppings = [ "Sausage" , "Pepperoni" , "Extra Cheese" , "Onions" ,"Black Olives" , "Anchovies" , "Pineapple" , "Canadian Bacon" , "Ground Beef" ];

       function ToppingsWanted()
       {

           var ingredients = document.pizzaForm.lstIngredients;

           var chosenOption = ingredients.options[ingredients.selectedIndex];

           selectedToppings.push(toppings[chosenOption.value]);

           alert(selectedToppings);
                           return selectedToppings
       }

   </script>
   ```

A few notes.

1. This is pretty redundant, you can just store the values which you are storing in the toppings array in the list option values themselves. That way if the toppings ever change you don't have to update two things.
2. This code will not ensure that toppings aren't added twice. I could create an extra extra extra cheese pizza.

Comment: I tried that, and while your code works, the function comes back as undefined in the textarea. I realized that I hinted at something and didn't make it clear enough in my post that I have the loop and the second array because the user is to be able to choose more than one topping for a pizza. I apologize for not making that clearer.

Comment: Sorry part of the code was cropped off. note the onChange="ToppingsWanted()" part of the select tag. This binds the function the the onChange event of the form. Copy this code, each time you select an ingredient in the form you should see it added to the selectToppings array, allowing one to choose more than one topping.